# Change parameters values on NestJs to another existant class

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I've two classes with some string parameters and I want to refactor a parameter type to a class.

```
export class CreateUpdateParcoursDto {
  @IsOptional()
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  startingNode: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(() => Category)
  category: Category;
}
```

```
@Entity()
export class Node {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  // Exp: name = "Validation de l'intention du cient"
  @Column({ unique: true })
  name: string;

  // Relation n-> n avec l'objet Connection
  @ManyToMany(() => Connection, (connection) => connection.nodes, {
    cascade: true,
    eager: true,
  })
  @JoinTable()
  connections: Connection[];

  // Relation n-> 1 avec l'objet Action
  @ManyToOne(() => Action, (action) => action.nodes)
  action: Action;
}
```

I want to change `startingNode string`  type into `Node` type , and I don't know which relationships should I use or change on my `controller` file, `service` file, and `repository` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your main.ts file and add tihs line

```
async function bootstrap() {
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
        logger: ['debug', 'error'],
        cors: true
    });
    const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);
    SwaggerModule.setup('api', app, document);

    app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({
      transform: true // this line here in your validationPipe
    }));
    await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

then you can go in your dto file and call @Transform decorator

```
export class CreateUpdateParcoursDto {
  @IsOptional()
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Transform(({ value }) => new Node({name: value})
  startingNode: Node;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(() => Category)
  category: Category;
}
```

And for the last step, you can take the initial parameter on your entity constructor

```
@Entity()
export class Node {
  constructor({name}) {
    this.name = name
  }
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  // Exp: name = "Validation de l'intention du cient"
  @Column({ unique: true })
  name: string;

  // Relation n-> n avec l'objet Connection
  @ManyToMany(() => Connection, (connection) => connection.nodes, {
    cascade: true,
    eager: true,
  })
  @JoinTable()
  connections: Connection[];

  // Relation n-> 1 avec l'objet Action
  @ManyToOne(() => Action, (action) => action.nodes)
  action: Action;
}
```

Comment: No problem! we are here to help each other.